# Why is my JSP login page not working? I have a valid username and password but the statement to compare the entered

Tags: mysql, sql, jsp, authentication

I have a valid username and password but the statement to compare the entered info to the database info is coming up as false.

Here is my login.jsp page

```html
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>New Life Inc</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>form</h1>

<%


String user = request.getParameter("user");
String pw = request.getParameter("pw");
String result="fail";

java.sql.Connection cn;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/newlife", "root", "1234");


PreparedStatement pstatement = null;
int updateQuery = 0;

String queryString = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE email = ? and password = ?";


              pstatement = cn.prepareStatement(queryString);
        pstatement.setString(1, user);
        pstatement.setString(2, pw);

              ResultSet theResult = pstatement.executeQuery();

                            if (theResult.next()){
                                result="sucess";         
       }
%>
<%=theResult.next()%> //all of these are scriptlets that just verify that my IF conditions
<%=user%>             //are coming up as false but user and pw match the database entry
<%=pw%>
</body>
</html>
```

I can verify that the MySQL database it connects to is correct and the SQL code SELECT statement returns one row (the user account I want to log in). I just need some info on how to compare the SQL statement results to my login credentials or even extract the column values for email and password so I can compare them in if statements.

Here is the sql schema for my user table

```
CREATE TABLE User (
fname                  VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
lname                  VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
dob                    DATE        NOT NULL,
sex                    VARCHAR(1),
email                  VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
password               VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
visitor                VARCHAR(1)  NOT NULL
);
```

email is being used as the username

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>New Life Inc</title>
</head>
<body>  
    <form>  
        <fieldset style="width: 300px">  
            <legend> Login to App </legend>  
            <table>  
                <tr>  
                    <td>User ID</td>  
                    <td><input type="text" name="user" required="required" /></td>  
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                    <td>Password</td>  
                    <td><input type="password" name="pw" required="required" /></td>  
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                    <td><input type="submit" name = "a" value="Login" /></td>  
                </tr>  
            </table>  
        </fieldset>  
    </form>  
</body> 
<%
    String user = request.getParameter("user");
  String pw = request.getParameter("pw");
  String chk = request.getParameter("a");
  String result="fail";
  ResultSet theResult=null;
  if("Login".equalsIgnoreCase(chk)){
        java.sql.Connection cn;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        cn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/newlife", "root", "");

        PreparedStatement pstatement = null;
        int updateQuery = 0;

        String queryString = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ? and password = ?";

        pstatement = cn.prepareStatement(queryString);
        pstatement.setString(1, user);
        pstatement.setString(2, pw);
        System.out.println(queryString);
        theResult = pstatement.executeQuery();

        if (theResult.next()) {
            result = "sucess";
            out.println("Login Sucess");
        } else {
            out.println("Login failed");
        }
    }
 %>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly. Im going to edit it a bit so it fits in with my existing login/signup page. Thanks so much, man!